# What does manager refer to in this code?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and trying to learn the code for Extreme Tux Racer. In the [code](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/src/main.cpp) in the main method it says manager.Run(...). To me this looks like it is running the Run method of a manager object in the State namespace.

```
switch (g_game.argument) {
        case 0:
            State::manager.Run(SplashScreen);
            break;
        case 4:
            g_game.toolmode = TUXSHAPE;
            State::manager.Run(Tools);
            break;
        case 9:
            State::manager.Run(OglTest);
            break;
    }
```

I assume that the manager object's run method has to be declared and defined somewhere. But I searched all of the included files for the word manager and could not find it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked its _base_ classes?

Comment: @timrau how do i do that? I only see these three references to manager in this file. How do I know what class manager is derived from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like they set file name the same as class name, which is a good way to do. So in [`states.h`](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/src/states.h), you could see all definition:

```
class State {
  //...
  static Manager manager;  // manager is static member
  //...
};
```

static member could be accessed by `::` , `.` or `->`  operator.

```
State::manager.Run(..); // valid
State state;
state.manager.Run(..);  // valid as well

State *pState = &state;
pState->manager.Run(..); // also valid
```

Comment: You are correct. https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/src/states.h But I thought State refers to the namespace, not the class name. Am I getting the syntax wrong? Doesn't a line of code that says A::b.c() mean namespace=A, class=b, method=c?

Comment: Class is also a namespace. You use the namespace operator to access static members inside a class.

Comment: yeah, static member could be accessed by :: or . operator.

Comment: Might be wise to clarify `::` when using class name, `.` or `->` when using object instance name.